# Do topological transitions only occur at Dirac points?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

Topological phase transitions happen when the band gap closes. It is not true that all band crossings are topological.

There are Dirac (linear) band crossings, quadratic band crossings, Dirac-like triply degenerate band crossings, double Dirac cone crossings, semi-Dirac transitions (linear in one direction and quadratic in another) etc.

Even in 1D, all the band crossings I recall look linear. In 2D, all the band crossings I recall are Dirac cones. I feel like I have been told that some quadratic dispersions can be a topological transition but I am not sure if I remember correctly.

Are all topological phase transitions in electronic bands/ photonic bands linear/ Dirac points?

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the aspect of classifying band closings at topological transitions to others, and focus on this statement:

> Topological phase transitions happen when the band gap closes.

Although that's the standard story, there's a growing understanding that you can actually have topological transitions without gap closings. These so-called first-order topological transitions require some degree of interaction between electrons (or possibly other constituent particles). Topological transitions in non-interacting electron systems should still be continuous, and have an associated gap closing.

Relevant literature:

- Amaricci et al. [*First order character and observable signatures of topological quantum phase transitions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7390), Phys. Rev. Lett. **114**, 185701 (2015).
- Imriška, Wang, and Troyer [*First order topological phase transition of the Haldane--Hubbard model*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03553), Phys. Rev. B **94**, 035109 (2016)
- Juricic, Abergel and Balatsky [*First-order quantum phase transition in three-dimensional topological band insulators*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07819), Phys. Rev. B **95**, 161403 (2017)